# Azman with multiple stores

Tags: multi-tenant, azman

I want to have a multi tenant feature for Azman, for Eg: Each hospital should have particular roles to task link.

Or in short multiple stores in single DB.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom role provider and have the following setup

1. Adding a `TenantId` as a column in the Roles Table
2. For every getting of the roles, get the union of the tenant specific roles and the global roles if any.
3. In case of a customization of the global role by a given tenant, use the privileges from the tenant context.
4. This also facilitates the copy of the global role to the tenant. However, your business demands should be considered as well for more details on the implementation.